# using regexp in ansible to replace word

Tags: ansible

I am newbie to ansible actually.Can anyone please help me change the ip address in a file using regexp with my original system ip.  Let say I wanted to replace "Djgroups.bind_address=<*/WHATEVER/BLANK>" to "Djgroups.bind_address=10.0.0.45"

This would be for a tomcat instance. The Line where the replacement is required:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djgroups.bind_address="
```

I Wrote ansible as below:

```
  - name: Verifying Instance IP Address
    shell: grep Djgroups.bind_address /apache-tomcat-8.5.15_1/bin/catalina.sh|grep -v ^#|tr -s '=' '"'|cut -d '"' -f5
    register: tomcat_instance_ip
  - debug: msg='Tomcat instance has {{ tomcat_instance_ip.stdout }} set.'

  - name: Updating Tomcat Instance with valid local IP address
    replace:
      dest: /apache-tomcat-8.5.15_1/bin/catalina.sh
      regexp: '^(Djgroups.bind_address(?!.*\b{{ tomcat_instance_ip.stdout }}\b).*)$'
      replace: '\1 {{ ip_address }}'
    when: tomcat_instance_ip.stdout != ip_address
```

Thanks, Sam

Comment: So what is the actual outcome of your solution? You should try to be specific about what is it exactly that does not work. You can also try out your regex here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Actually the below line i have written does not change the ip address section with system ip address. `regexp: '^(Djgroups.bind_address(?!.*\b{{ tomcat_instance_ip.stdout }}\b).*)$'
      replace: '\1 {{ ip_address }}'` am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `shell` task, this is not needed.

Try this :

```
- name: Updating Tomcat Instance with valid local IP address
  replace:
    path: /apache-tomcat-8.5.15_1/bin/catalina.sh
    regexp: 'JAVA_OPTS="(.* )?-Djgroups.bind_address=[^ "]*(.*)"'
    replace: 'JAVA_OPTS="\1-Djgroups.bind_address={{ ip_address }}\2"'
```

The `when` is not needed either, since `replace` module is idempotent.

**Edit :** some explanations about the regular expression used in this example

```
'JAVA_OPTS="(.* )?-Djgroups.bind_address=[^ "]*(.*)"'
            ^___^                              ^__^
 ^_________^ (1) ^______________________^       (2)
      (3)                     (4)
                                         ^__^
                                          (5)
```

- *1* and *2* are the "unknown" parts. This can be anything and we don't want to lose this while applying the replacement. So we capture them with parenthesis. We can re-use them in the replacement by referencing them with `\1` and `\2`.
- *3* and *4* are the "known" parts. They are used to identify the line to be modified. We don't really need to capture them since we actually know their contents.
- *5* is the interesting part, this is what we want to replace with new content. We don't care about its actual content.

[Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are somewhat intimidating at first, with this weird syntax. This not as complicated as it seems. You can find a lot of [tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expressions+tutorial) to help you understand it.

Comment: For my learning, can you please explain the regexp and replace section as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SamironMallick I edited my answer with a short explanation. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you Eric for in depth explanation

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 4 issues with the regexp:

1. your `.` is not escaped, so it is interpreted as a special character.
2. Why do you put `^` at the beginning. Seems like you are trying to find something in the middle of a string, not at the beginning.
3. you should use lazy evaluation for the .* in negative lookup. Right now it will match anything.
4. you are trying to match the `Djgroups.bind_address` part of the string, while i believe you meant to match whatever comes afterwards instead.

try: `Djgroups\.bind_address=(?!.*?{{ tomcat_instance_ip.stdout }}.*?)(.*)$`

And please test your regex first. https://regex101.com/ Make sure it actually matches your input like you imagined.